# Will it return my method name if called

Tags: java

```
private IPerson savePerson;

    public IContact getsaveContact() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        //info("Coming Here");
        return savePerson;
    }

    public void setsaveContact(IPerson contact) {
        this.savePerson= savePerson;
    }

package 

import Contact;

public interface IPerson {

    public void savePerson(Contact contact);

}
```

I have an interface IPerson with methodname savePerson. I need to access that method name. What i do is above, when i call my getsaveContact method will it return savePerson method name of my Interface

I dont want to implement the interface at all, but i need to call the method name inside through some way... i heard we can do it via getter and setter methods.

Comment: unclear question, will you please elaborate bit more with compilable code

Comment: you are really not using the proper terms here, so your question doesn't make much sense. Please make sure you understand the concepts and their names - interface, method, method name, field, etc.

Comment: not clear what you are asking...

Comment: I dont want to implement the interface at all, but i need to call the method name inside through some way... i heard we can do it via getter and setter methods.

Comment: there is no such thing as "call the method name". You want to call the method? Or do something with its name?

Comment: I want to call the method name without implementing the interface.

Comment: Some people here asked you to clarify your question, but all you've done is copy/paste a part of it in a comment. How do you expect this to be a better explanation of what your problem is ?

Comment: Do you want to "call the method 'name'", as in "there is a method `public Foo name()` somewhere and I want to call it"...

Comment: yes its inside the interface but i dont want to implement the interface in my class and use that method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking if

```
public IContact getsaveContact() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    //info("Coming Here");
    return savePerson;
}
```

Will return the name of the savePerson method. Then no. This code returns the IPerson object defined in

```
private IPerson savePerson;
```

Answer (score 1):

this looks like an error to me:

```
public void setsaveContact(IPerson contact) {
     this.savePerson= savePerson;
 }
```

im guessing this should be:

```
public void setsaveContact(IPerson contact) {
     this.savePerson= contact;
 }
```